# InputType of EditText in Android

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

I want to use default keyboard for, but want also that it occurs with numeric input type.

Does anybody know how to do that?

Maybe there is a way to press '?123'-key programmatically?

I've took a look to [list of inputTypes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType), but none of them seems to be the proper one for my need.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either of these 3:

[image]

For example: `android:inputType="numberDecimal"`

Comment: I've tried it already and I coulds swear I've got only numbers without posibility to change to lettes. Now I know, why I thought so. I've tried it on HTC Tattoo

Answer (score 0):

set in ur code 
 `inputType = "number"`