# InputType of EditText in Android

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

I would like to have following:
- number keyboard should be displayed first
- but it should be possible to change to text keyboard and to type some letters.

I've asked almost the same question and accepted an answer.
[InputType of EditText in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931494/inputtype-of-edittext-in-android)

But now I found some strange behaviour, setting **InputType** to **Number**: it is possible to change keyboard to text type, but it's impossible to type some text.

Any Ideas, why does it happen_

Does anybody know how to use **TYPE_MASK_CLASS** as input type?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right and I didn't find any answer to that except if you wrote your own keyboard.
TYPE_MASK_CLASS is for masking class of EditorInfo in keyboard development.

Answer (score 0):

android:inputType="textPersonName|number|numberSigned|numberDecimal"

Paste it for Numerical Input type

android:inputType="text|textCapCharacters|textCapWords|textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect|textAutoComplete|textMultiLine|textImeMultiLine|textPersonName"
Paste it for Alphabetical Input type