# How open specific page of keyboard?

Tags: android, layout, keyboard

In one of my edittext fields users can enter numeric values and colons. These keys are part of one specific page of the keyboard. I would like to open that specific page if the users enters the corresponding edittext field. If there's a XML attribute for the layout it would be even better.

Many thanks in advance.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

- To display pure numeric keyboard use  `android:inputType="phone"`
- The `android:inputType="time"` is the best options for time input. It
  will let you input numbers and colon '**:**'.
- For *'Known Distance'* and *'Distance to estimate'* you can use
  `android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"`. It will let you input
  numbers with dots i.e double or floats.

You can use `android:inputType="number"` for Numbers. Here is an example of EditText which opens phone with digits-numbers Keyboard.

```
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/test"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
```

Here is a [small example](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/07/some-examples-of-inputtype-on-edittext.html) of using inputType in layout.
You can use following values in inputType field.

- none
- text
- textCapCharacters
- textCapWords
- textCapSentences
- textAutoCorrect
- textAutoComplete
- textMultiLine
- textImeMultiLine
- textNoSuggestions
- textUri
- textEmailAddress
- textEmailSubject
- textShortMessage
- textLongMessage
- textPersonName
- textPostalAddress
- textPassword
- textVisiblePassword
- textWebEditText
- textFilter
- textPhonetic
- textWebEmailAddress
- textWebPassword
- number
- numberSigned
- numberDecimal
- numberPassword
- phone
- datetime
- date
- time

Here is [detailed explanation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType) about it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I saw these static values and tried them already but the keyboard in the picture is not the numeric keyboard. It's some sort of page two of the standard keyboard.

Comment: @Harald use android:inputType="phone". This will display a numeric keyboard. Hope that it will solve your problem

Comment: The phone pad does not contain the colon. That's why I try to open that specific keyboard layout shwn above automatically.

Comment: @Harald modified answer at top. The android:inputType="time" is the best options. It will let you input digits and colon. For Known Distance and Distance to estimate you can use android:inputType="number|numberDecimal". It will let you input numbers with dots

Comment: Thanks for your answer. android:inputType="time" sounds promising but does not open a keyboard with a colon. It simply shows the same keyboard with dot, minus - but no colon (as android:inputType="numberDecimal"). This is on a real device Google Nexus One running Android 2.3.7. Hmm, what's wrong with my code?

Comment: It looks strange android:inputType="time" works fine at my side. It also have colon. And I can input colon in EditText.

Comment: Seems that the Android fragmentation bites here. On my devices some show the correct keyboard layout with inputType="time" - some not.

Answer (score 0):

According to [InputType of EditText in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069699/inputtype-of-edittext-in-android/5082343#5082343) and other answers here, the only way is to make your own class of keyboard. Or find some ready on the net.